# jQuery: scroll to top of element with animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to scroll to the top of elements with animation once the element is clicked on.

However, I can't seem be able to achieve this.

This is a fiddle with my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/3dqzsu2m/1/

and this is my code:

```
$('.newins').on('focus', function() {
var off = $(this).offset().top;

    $('.scroll').animate({ scrollTop: off }, 2000);

});
```

could someone please let me know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is no scroll in ".scroll" div. Your parent element with scroll is "body".

Look at this code.

https://jsfiddle.net/3dqzsu2m/2/

If you want to use ".scroll" div, you must add height to it.

```
.scroll{
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3dqzsu2m/4/